# pacman (arch linux package manager) outgoing comunication port

Tags: arch-linux, iptables, tcp, pacman

I have to block all outgoing connections on ports that are not used, but i can not find the port used by [pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman) to synchronize and update/install packages. On the internet, i found that [pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman) uses either `http` or `ftp` protocols depending on the repos, so when i allow only those protocols using `iptables` and try to install a package i receive connection related errors.

Does pacman uses dynamic ports or specific prots ?

here is an example of what i was doing:
The os is in a VM
[This](http://archlinux.de-labrusse.fr/iso/2019.06.01/) version of arch.

```bsh
user@archlinux ~> sudo iptables -F
user@archlinux ~> sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p TCP --sport 1:500 -j ACCEPT
user@archlinux ~> sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p TCP --sport 4242 -j ACCEPT # My ssh connection
user@archlinux ~> sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p UDP --sport 1:500 -j ACCEPT
user@archlinux ~> sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
user@archlinux ~> sudo pacman -S mariadb
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (5) jemalloc-1:5.2.0-1  lzo-2.10-2  mariadb-clients-10.4.6-1  mariadb-libs-10.4.6-1  mariadb-10.4.6-1

Total Download Size:    45.61 MiB
Total Installed Size:  290.92 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
:: Retrieving packages...
error: failed retrieving file 'lzo-2.10-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.xtom.com.hk : Could not resolve host: mirror.xtom.com.hk
error: failed retrieving file 'lzo-2.10-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.surlyjake.com : Could not resolve host: archlinux.surlyjake.com
error: failed retrieving file 'lzo-2.10-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.datacenter.by : Could not resolve host: mirror.datacenter.by
error: failed retrieving file 'lzo-2.10-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.za.mirror.allworldit.com : Could not resolve host: archlinux.za.mirror.allworldit.com
error: failed retrieving file 'lzo-2.10-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.iskon.hr : Could not resolve host: archlinux.iskon.hr
error: failed retrieving file 'lzo-2.10-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.vectranet.pl : Could not resolve host: ftp.vectranet.pl
error: failed retrieving file 'lzo-2.10-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.netcologne.de : Could not resolve host: mirror.netcologne.de
error: failed retrieving file 'lzo-2.10-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.0x.sg : Could not resolve host: mirror.0x.sg
error: failed retrieving file 'lzo-2.10-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.umd.edu : Could not resolve host: mirror.umd.edu
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your examples filter outbound connections based on their soruce port, not outbound connections based on their destination port. This is rather uncommon and does not really make sense security-wise. Are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an problem with the DNS resolving. You have to allow the port 53 UDP outgoing for DNS.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

`pacman` uses HTTP and HTTPS for downloading packages. Which one depends on the contents of your /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.